# How should I store and use my 500kB data file in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

So I have 0.5MB XML file with data for my iPhone application. It's all read-only so I don't have to bother with writing.

Currently I'm using NSXMLParser to load data.

I had fun with NSXMLParser and I created a class that loads only the part of data that I currently need. So once the file is parsed it takes minimum of memory.

But it's very slow. It takes 500-1000ms to parse the XML file and find the part of data that I need on my iPad.

I could load all the data at once and than just use it. That would definitely save me from all the XML loading and parsing, but then I would have 500kB NSArray or something. I don't particularly like that idea.

I was wondering if there's any way to do this that wouldn't take much memory and would be fast too.

Any ideas please?

**Updates:**

Thanks everyone for answers. So it looks like these two options are the best for this case:

1. Archiving XML data into binary form. It will be processed very quickly, and 500kB is really not that much to stay in the memory.
2. If I really wanted to make it super-memory-efficient, than there's SQLite or Core Data.

I think I'm gonna try and implement number one.

Comment: Does the source file need to be monolithic XML? Could you preprocess and store the data in some other way (chunked? plist?)? Loading speed aside, if your main memory data structure is under 1MB, you shouldn't sweat its footprint. That's nothin'.

Comment: Yeah I could reprocess it and store in some other way. What do you suggest? I think some kind of binary form would be great, but I don't really know much about this stuff. I don't want to get too complicated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 KB really is not that much. To put it in perspective, loading a full screen image as a background on your iPad uses 2.9 MB.

So, personally I would just load all data in memory and operate it directly.

I would also convert from XML to an archived NSArray or NSDictionary. That should make the initial loading very very fast.

Comment: So is there any easy way to archive NSArray? I mean how should I save it?

Comment: Vojto: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/

Comment: While 500k isn't a lot of data, it's still a big XML tree to have to parse through repeatedly. Data size isn't tied to data complexity,

Comment: Matthew, that is why i commented that I would also convert the XML to a native data structure. I'm sure it is then even smaller in memory. And if you index it properly, even with something as simple as an NSDictionary, lookups should be really fast.

Comment: Gotcha, I should have read your response more thoroughly rather than reacting to the first part so quickly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the perfect case for using a database, either using SQLite directly or via Core Data. It's exactly what databases do, accessing portions of a larger data set quickly and easily.

Is there a compelling reason to leave your data in a giant XML file?

Comment: +1 for core data / sqllite, especially as it sounds like it needs to be queried

Comment: Sounds good. I just didn't want to think about moving my data from XML to SQL at first, but looks like that would be the best way around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard C calls and data structures to read and process a file. So, anything you would do to make things efficient in C will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a (binary) plist instead. There really isn't any need to overcomplicate it with CoreData/SQL/stream-based XML parsing when it all easily fits in memory.

You might get a small decrease in load time by using SQLite instead of reading the whole plist at startup, but probably at an increased access time cost, and it really isn't worth worrying about this until you hit it. If it's that big a deal, there are many simple things you can do like saving each "part" to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use GDataXML (http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) it supports XPath Expressions what makes it very easy to only get the parts you want.